# Angular 7.2.0: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'RunGuardsAndResolvers'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-router

Angular compiler-cli v.7.2.0 is throwing:

> Types of property 'runGuardsAndResolvers' are incompatible.   Type
>   'string' is not assignable to type 'RunGuardsAndResolvers'

when setting `runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'` in a constant which is imported into `AppRoutingModule`.

This does not occur when I set `runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'` within `AppRoutingModule` itself.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { adminRouterConfig } from 'src/app/core/_routing/admin-router-config';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      ...adminRouterConfig
    ]
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
  ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes,
                                 { enableTracing: true }
)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**admin-router-config.ts**

```
import { AuthGuard } from 'src/app/core/_guards/auth.guard';

export const adminRouterConfig = [
  {
    path: 'admin',
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      ...
    ]
  }
];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just the way type inference works in TypeScript.
When you first assign it to a variable, it will infer the type for the variable to `{runGuardsAndResolvers: string}` and then it doesn't match when it is used later. In this case, you have to specify the type explicitly:

```
const options = {
  runGuardsAndResolvers: "always" as RunGuardsAndResolvers
};
```

---

Have a look at this example:

```
const method = (options: { runGuardsAndResolvers: RunGuardsAndResolvers }) => {
  return options;
};

// This works
method({ runGuardsAndResolvers: "always" });

// This fails
const options = { runGuardsAndResolvers: "always" };
method(options);

// This works
const typedOptions = {
  runGuardsAndResolvers: "always" as RunGuardsAndResolvers
};
method(typedOptions);
```

Live demo:

[image: Edit Typescript type inference]